# How to extract font family from OOXML using Apache POI?

Tags: java, parsing, apache-poi, openxml, docx

I am trying to extract the font style that is applied to a specific paragraph with [Apache POI](https://poi.apache.org/components/document/). The method `getStyle()` returns null on the my `XWPFParagraph` object.

Calling the method `getCTR().getRPr().getRStyle()` on the first `XWPFRun` object also returns null.

Calling the method `getStyle().getDocDefaults().getRPrDefault()` on my `XWPFDocument` object returns this:

```
    <w:rPr>
      <w:rFonts w:asciiTheme="minorHAnsi"/>
      <w:sz w:val="22"/>
      <w:szCs w:val="22"/>
      <w:lang w:val="en-GB" w:eastAsia="en-US" w:bidi="ar-SA"/>
    </w:rPr>
```

Where there are no `w:ascii` attribute in the `w:rFonts` tag. There is however a `w:asciiTheme` attribute declared in the tag. How can I extract the information under the given theme with Apache POI?

The font style for this example is defined as the theme `minorHAnsi` and the theme can be found in the theme1.xml file. But how can I for example extract the attribute under the `a:latin` tag using Apache POI?
Here is an sample from what it looks like in the theme1.xml file:

```
<a:minorFont>
   <a:latin typeface="Calibri"/>
   <a:ea typeface=""/>
   <a:cs typeface=""/>
   <a:font script="Jpan" typeface="ＭＳ 明朝"/>
   <a:font script="Hang" typeface="맑은 고딕"/>
   <a:font script="Hans" typeface="宋体"/>
                   ...
   <a:font script="Viet" typeface="Arial"/>
   <a:font script="Uigh" typeface="Microsoft Uighur"/>
   <a:font script="Geor" typeface="Sylfaen"/>
</a:minorFont>
```

Comment: Try fetching the style on the first `XWPFRun` in the Paragraph?

Comment: Have tried that, it also returns null. This is what the run contains:
`<w:rPr>
    <w:sz w:val="36"/>
    <w:szCs w:val="36"/>
</w:rPr>
<w:t>Some text..</w:t>`

Comment: What do you expect as answer? You seems to know the internal structure of the `*.docx` file. You know, there is the `/word/theme/theme1.xml`. You know `apache poi` does not yet providing access to this document part. So only way would be getting that document part from the [OPCPackage](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/openxml4j/opc/OPCPackage.htm). Then parsing that `XML` using methods outside `apache poi` and providing methods to get information out of it. Much too broad for an answer here.

Answer (score 0):

If the question is how to get the `/word/theme/theme1.xml` out of the `*.docx` file system, then how to parse that and then get `<a:minorFont><a:latin...` out of it, then this could be solved like so:

First do using methods of [OPCPackage](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/openxml4j/opc/OPCPackage.html) to get the package part `/word/theme/theme1.xml`.

```
...
  XWPFDocument document = new XWPFDocument(new FileInputStream("./WordExample.docx"));
  OPCPackage oPCPackage = document.getPackage();
  PackagePartName partName = PackagingURIHelper.createPartName("/word/theme/theme1.xml");
  PackagePart themePart = oPCPackage.getPart(partName);
...
```

Then, if we have that `PackagePart`, do parsing that into a `org.openxmlformats.schemas.drawingml.x2006.main.ThemeDocument`. Then do using methods of `org.openxmlformats.schemas.drawingml.x2006.main.ThemeDocument` to get the child elements of that.

```
...
  ThemeDocument themeDocument = ThemeDocument.Factory.parse(themePart.getInputStream());
  CTOfficeStyleSheet theme = themeDocument.getTheme();
  CTBaseStyles themeElements = theme.getThemeElements();
  CTFontScheme fontScheme = themeElements.getFontScheme();
  CTFontCollection minorFont = fontScheme.getMinorFont();
  CTTextFont latin = minorFont.getLatin();
...
```

Unfortunately there is no `API` documentation of `org.openxmlformats.schemas.*` public available. So, to get a such, we need downloading sources of `ooxml-schemas` (for example from https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/poi/ooxml-schemas/1.4/) and then using `javadoc` to create a `API` documentation from the sources.

Complete example:

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;

import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.*;
import org.openxmlformats.schemas.drawingml.x2006.main.*;

public class WordGetThemeDocument {

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

  XWPFDocument document = new XWPFDocument(new FileInputStream("./WordExample.docx"));
  OPCPackage oPCPackage = document.getPackage();
  PackagePartName partName = PackagingURIHelper.createPartName("/word/theme/theme1.xml");
  PackagePart themePart = oPCPackage.getPart(partName);
System.out.println(themePart);

  ThemeDocument themeDocument = ThemeDocument.Factory.parse(themePart.getInputStream());
  CTOfficeStyleSheet theme = themeDocument.getTheme();
  CTBaseStyles themeElements = theme.getThemeElements();
  CTFontScheme fontScheme = themeElements.getFontScheme();
  CTFontCollection minorFont = fontScheme.getMinorFont();
  CTTextFont latin = minorFont.getLatin();
System.out.println(latin);
  String typeFace = latin.getTypeface();
System.out.println(typeFace);

  document.close();
 }

}
```